# relation between isomorphism as $F[t]$-module and similar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ square matrices with entries in a field $F$. Then prove that $A,B$ are similar if and only if $F_{A}^{n}, F_{B}^{n}$ are isomorphic as $F[t]$-modules, where $F_{A}^{n}, F_{B}^{n}$ means $n$-dimensional vector spaces with linear operators $L_A, L_B$ : $F^n\rightarrow F^n$, respectively.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are similar, there is an obvious isomorphism of $F[t]$-modules.

---

So suppose the two $F[t]$-modules are isomorphic through $\phi:F^n_A\to F^n_B$. This means that $\phi:F^n\to F^n$ is an isomorphism of $F$-vector spaces such that for all $x\in F^n$, $\phi(t.x)=t.\phi(x)$, i.e.
$$\forall x\in F^n,\qquad \phi(Ax)=B\phi(x)$$
If you identify $\phi$ with its matrix in the canonical basis (as you have implicitely done with $A$ and $B$), this means that there is a matrix $\phi\in\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ such that for all $x\in F^n$
$$\phi A x=B\phi x$$
i.e. for all $x\in F^n$
$$\big(B-\phi A\phi^{-1}\big)x=0\,.$$
This means that $B-\phi A\phi^{-1}=0$, i.e. $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Comment: What is the obvious isomorphism if A and B are similar?

Comment: Any linear isomorphism $u: F^n_A \to F^n_B$ such that $B = uAu^{-1}$.